# Casos de uso parar auth()->user() y Auth::user()

Tags: laravel-8

Leí la documentación de Laravel y he examidado lo que retornan ambos métodos, y tengo claro que retornan lo mismo, pero no entiendo cuándo me conviene usar cada opción. Podría no complicarme y usar siempre el helper, por ejemplo, pero me gustaría saber la razón de cada una de esas opciones.

Por cierto, sé en qué consisten ambos métodos, lo que me interesa saber es cuándo es mejor usar uno u otro, y por qué.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta la tienes en [este post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/difference-between-auth-user-id-and-authuser-id).

Hacen los mismo, solo que `auth()` llama al helper y `Auth::` llama al facade

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El asunto, es que eso lo tengo claro. Lo que quiero saber es en qué contextos es mejor usar uno u otro.

Comment: Hay una respuesta en ese mismo post que explica que auth() es util a la hora de llamar a las vistas,  ya que no necesita el namespace, el cual es necesario al usar facade